# iPhone SDK: How can I write an audio file picked from iPod Library into my app's Documents Folder?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, ipod, mpmediapickercontroller

How can I write an audio file picked from `mediaPicker` into my app's Documents Folder?

Basically I am selecting a audio file from iPod Library.

I want that this selected file be copied into my app's Documents folder.

So that I can reference it from my app's Documents folder.

What can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to convert iPod libray song and write it to documents directory, using

[From iPod Library to PCM Samples in Far Fewer Steps Than Were Previously Necessary](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/)

Thanks Mats Stijlaart for your help. But I got the solution for this.

Hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend TSLibraryImport in iOS4+

http://code.google.com/p/tslibraryimport/

https://bitbucket.org/artgillespie/tslibraryimport

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is allowed. This will make it more easy to copy file bought in iTunes, so i do not think apple will allow that.

When you pick music from your music library, you will have to use a MPMediaPickerController with the following delegate method:

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
```

MPMediaItemCollection is some kind of list. It's items are instances of the MPConcreteMediaItem class. The MPMusicPlayerController can play a MPMediaItemCollection, but with MPConcreteMediaItems but you can not do anything.

Comment: Thanks for input, Can I store references of MPMediaItemCollection somewhere? I mean path of that file, to use that file next time I open my app?

Comment: MPMediaItemCollection inherits from MPMediaEntity which inherits from NSObject. MPMediaEntity is conform to the NSCoding protocol, so it means it is serializable and you can put the data in a file. <br/> This means you can also serialize a MPMediaItemCollection. I do not know if it will work, but i'm almost certain apple did implement it (probably the way Apple stores playlists).